# Cuda support on GeForce G210M

Tags: cuda

I am trying to set up Cuda on my laptop with GeForce G210M, but I am not sure which architecture should I use while compile
     nvcc -arch=...

Here is my DeviceQuery output:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce G210M"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.0 / 5.5
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.2
Total amount of global memory:                 511 MBytes (536150016 bytes)
( 2) Multiprocessors, (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:     16 CUDA Cores
GPU Clock rate:                                1468 MHz (1.47 GHz)
Memory Clock rate:                             500 Mhz
Memory Bus Width:                              64-bit
Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(8192), 2D=(65536, 32768), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(8192), 512 layers
Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(8192, 8192), 512 layers
Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
Total number of registers available per block: 16384
Warp size:                                     32
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
Maximum number of threads per block:           512
Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (512, 512, 64)
Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 1)
Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           1 / 0
Compute Mode:
 < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 6.0, CUDA    Runtime Version = 5.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce G210M
Result = PASS
```

Comment: The CUDA capability version number is the compute capability version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you're looking for is the one with the `compute capability`.

> CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.2

You should therefore use the flag `-arch=sm_12` during compilation:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_12
```